# namespace Microsoft vs namespace Windows

Tags: windows, c++-winrt, winui

I am trying C++/WinRT and the WinUI templates available in VisualStudio. I am confused about namespaces `::winrt::Microsoft` and `::winrt::Windows`. I only know about the former one because auto-generated callback functions used a type from `::winrt::Microsoft`, and wouldn't compile because I passed identically named type from `::winrt::Windows` namespace by mistake. I couldn't find more information about `::winrt::Microsoft`, couldn't even find official documentation.

From what I can say, `::winrt::Microsoft` and `::winrt::Windows` have mostly identically named types, but some types are missing from `::winrt::Microsoft`. For example, `::winrt::Windows::UI::Colors` and `::winrt::Microsoft::UI::Colors` both exist, but `::winrt::Windows::UI::Color` has no "alternative" in the Microsoft namespace.

Questions:

- Why do we have 2 almost the same but subtly different namespaces?
- Under which circumstances do I choose one or the other?
- Why `::winrt::Microsoft` is missing some types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Windows` is the original namespace, where all UI-related types live. Some of those types were 'reinvented' into the `Microsoft` namespace as part of moving [WinUI](https://microsoft.github.io/microsoft-ui-xaml/) out of its UWP-only misery.

If a type is available in the (newer) `Microsoft` namespace then use that. The transition is not yet complete, so some types are missing.

Comment: More specifically, `Windows` is part of Windows. `Microsoft` is something by Microsoft but not part of Windows. There is an ongoing effort to detach many technologies from Windows, as you noted.

Comment: @Ray do you mean they are trying to make WinUI cross platform?

Comment: Making WinUI a cross-platform GUI framework is not an immediate goal of the effort to pull it out of the OS. Doing so rather allows WinUI to progress at its own pace, without having to wait for a new version of Windows to deploy it. At least equally important is the aspect that making WinUI a standalone library opens the opportunity to backport it to previous versions of the OS. More information on how this fits into the larger scale of moving the developer platform forward is published in the [Project Reunion](https://github.com/microsoft/ProjectReunion) repository.

Comment: Right. Detaching it from Windows means it doesn't have to wait for the next version of Windows before it can add features or fix bugs. (The detachment is in terms of delivery schedule, not supported platforms.)